# JMeter - can not assign password variable correctly

Tags: authentication, jmeter, passwords

I set username and password from CSV file `user:sysadmin, pass:"Pass@123456"` but password is encrypted wrong upon request

```
User=sysadmin&Pass=Pass%40123456
```

Comment: Please provide a little details about your configuration

Answer (score 2):

The fact you see it as `Pass@123456` doesn't necessarily mean that JMeter is sending wrong data, it might be either by intention due to string-based request representation in `Raw` form of request inspection in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener or by accident (just a bug in it. You can check [JMeter Issue Tracker](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) to see whether similar issues were reported already)

In the mean time try switching to the `HTTP` tab of the View Results Tree listener:

[image: JMeter View Results Tree]

Or double check what you're sending using a sniffer tool like Fiddler or Wireshark

[image: JMeter Wireshark Inspect Request]

But first of all I would recommend verifying your CSV data via [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) or temporarily switching to hard-coded (not parameterized) data to see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Another point, my application seems to only use body data. When I tried to change to use parameters, it can not login successfully. Although it is ok if I use body data

Answer (score 1):

@ is encoded when sending HTTP request.

You need to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)  with variable name `Content-Type` with value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
This will tell the server that the values need to be decoded

Comment: I added Header Manager with content-type application/json;charset=utf-8 but it is still fail. I copied HTTP header manager from recording but it is not successful  POST data:
User=sysadmin&Pass=Pass%40123456

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: ${path}/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

Comment: Show the HTTP request in JMeter

Comment: It also seems that path variable is not found